# Eager-load and pagination

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, pagination, array, eager-loading

I'm currently working on a relation-heavy website with a colleague of mine and, for that reason, eager-loading stuff looks very appealing to us.
We've succeeded in eager-loading pretty much everything that we needed but there is just one kind of template that we couldn't make it work with: paginated archives

**The context:**
We have this archive page that loads every entry of a 'projects' section and, next to each entry, we have a list of all images that the entry contains which is between 8-20 images (remember, I said it was relation-heavy ;) ). We care a lot about performance so we decided to paginate this big entry listing.

**The issue:**
All this works very well except that when we tried to eager-load those images, we transformed our original query which was:

```
{% set allProjects = craft.entries(queryParams).limit(itemsPerPage) %}
```

to

```
{% set allProjects = craft.entries(queryParams).limit(itemsPerPage).find({
    with: [
        'gridMatrixBlock1:rowItem1',
        ['gridMatrixBlock1:rowItem1.gridimageFile', {
            kind: 'image',
            withTransforms: projectThumb
        }],
        ...
    ]
}) %}
```

**The question:**
Since .find() returns an array, we have no way to paginate this (pagination need an ElementCriteriaModel). Is there any workaround I don't know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with` is just another query param, like `limit` or whatever parameters you’re defining in `entryParams`.

The `{% paginate %}` tag requires that you pass in an ElementCriteriaModel, but as soon as you call `find()` you’re actually dealing with an array of the matched entries.

So the key to getting eager-loading working with pagination is to assign the `with` param like any other param, rather than passing it into the find() function.

```
{% set queryParams = {
    // ...
    with: [
        'gridMatrixBlock1:rowItem1',
        ['gridMatrixBlock1:rowItem1.gridimageFile', {
            kind: 'image',
            withTransforms: projectThumb
        }],
        ...
    ]
} %}
```

and then you can create your ElementCriteriaModel just like you were doing before:

```
{% set allProjects = craft.entries(queryParams).limit(itemsPerPage) %}
```

Comment: That's perfect Brandon! I didn't know we could also do it like this (which I personally prefer). Thanks!