# Pagination and Entry Model on Homepage

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, pagination, array

On my site I have some entries with images. In the entry template I paginate the images like so:

```
{% paginate entry.images.limit(1) as images %}
```

My homepage is a single random entry and I want to paginate it as well. The Problem is, paginate expects an elementcriteriamodel, not an array. So this doesn't work:

```
{%
set project = craft.entries()
    .section('projects')
    .orderBy('RAND()')
    .with([
        ['images', { withTransforms: 'width' }],
        ['category']
    ])
    .one() %}
{% paginate project.images.limit(1) as images %}
```

I tried [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/eager-load-and-pagination), but that somehow doesn't work in Craft 3.

```
{% set queryParams = {
    with:[['images', { withTransforms: 'width' }],['category']]
}
%}

{%
set project = craft.entries(queryParams)
    .section('projects')
    .orderBy('RAND()')
    .one() %}

{% paginate project.images.limit(1) as images %}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`project.images` is an array because you are eager-loading the images.

Since you’re only loading one project entry, you’re not actually gaining anything by eager-loading the images (or category), though. In fact, you’re actually slowing things down a bit. Eager-loading does come with a little bit of overhead, so you should only use it when you’ve got an “n+1” problem, as described on the [Eager-Loading Entries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) page.

So to get this working, just remove the `with` param.

```twig
{% set project = craft.entries()
    .section('projects')
    .orderBy('RAND()')
    .one() %}

{% paginate project.images.limit(1) as images %}
```

Note that this will also affect how you access your category, as `project.category` will go from an eager-loaded array, back to a [category query](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/category-queries.html).